# Need help identifying this code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, markdown

What is this written in, and how can I convert it to HTML?
http://pastebin.com/ePPXkhMP

I need to edit it, but not sure how to convert it to HTML. I need to style it, but not sure how to start. Thought it was markdown but its not. Maybe its coffeescript, but I thought that was for Javascript. Do I need to convert from coffeescript to javascript then from javascript to something? I'm a bit lost.

Developer is not available for comment right now.

Cheers!

Comment: At the very least you should include an example of the text in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) [Template](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates) that you can build up with CoffeeKup(as said, and linked, in another answer), but then you'll need AngularJS to reuse it!

[Angular Script](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script)

[Angular Dynamic Templates](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they're using Coffeescript with a library called [CoffeeKup](http://coffeekup.org/). CoffeeKup allows you to make HTML pages using Coffeescript. If you check out the [CoffeeKup GitHub repo](https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup) they've got intructions on compiling CoffeeKup templates to plain HTML in the `README`.

As for styling, you could compile the HTML and include a CSS stylesheet from there. Otherwise, you would probably have to use a Node.js web framework to render the CoffeeKup templates themselves with stylesheets.